# Weird behaviour when querying Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I set up a brand new code in Solr and did not change any of the default settings. I indexed the two following files:

```
<add>
<doc>
<field name="id">weight loss</field>
<field name="text_en">weight loss</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

and

```
<add>
<doc>
<field name="id">weight loss2</field>
<field name="text_en">I strongly suspect that weight loss .</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

I execute a simple the simple phrase query:

```
select?hl.fl=text_en&hl=on&indent=on&q="weight loss"&wt=json
```

I'm getting both files as results but no highlighting!

```
  "response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"weight loss",
        "text_en":["weight loss"],
        "_version_":1545688757336801280},
      {
        "id":"weight loss2",
        "text_en":["I strongly suspect that weight loss ."],
        "_version_":1545688757344141312}]
  },
  "highlighting":{
    "weight loss":{},
    "weight loss2":{}}}
```

When I add the parameter *df=text_en* in the query mentioned before, I do get highlighting but only one result!

```
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"weight loss",
        "text_en":["weight loss"],
        "_version_":1545688757336801280}]
  },
  "highlighting":{
    "weight loss":{
      "text_en":["<em>weight loss</em>"]}}}
```

Also when I include the *df=text_en* parameter but remove the quotes from the phrase term:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test2/select?df=text_en&hl.fl=text_en&hl=on&indent=on&q=weight loss&wt=json
```

I do not understand this behaviour at all. Why am I not getting highlighting in the first case? Why a single match and no matches in second and third cases respectively?

Comment: You need to change the type for **text_en** to the **text_general** in the managed schema in order to get highlight for second case.`<field name="text_en" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type for **text_en** to the text_general, So that you will start getting highlight for all the case.

```
<field name="text_en" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```